# how can I set the first week of april for this excel formula? =WEEKNUM(A1)

Tags: excel

How can I set the first day and week of April for this excel formula?  =WEEKNUM(A1)
Because =WEEKNUM(A1) only works for January 1 or the first week of January.

Because our company Financial/Fiscal Year starts on April 1st. I need to get the week number of each day in a year and it's corresponding WEEKNUMBER, but the First day should be April 1 and not January 1. I will use this on my Time Dimension worksheet that I will import through ETL(SSIS)

Thanks and Regards,

Beau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the A1 date by subtracting from it the number of days in January, February and March (which of course depends on the year due to leap years):

```
=WEEKNUM(A1-(1 + DATE(YEAR(A1),3,31)-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I've noticed that the first day of the week in this formula starts on Saturday, would it be possible to tweak the formula to set Sunday as the first day of the week? I'm really not in good in excel.

Comment: I can't see how this is based on 1st April, so can't update it to be based upon a 1st July FY start. Can you advise?

Comment: @aSystemOverload A bit late to respond, but the relation to april is `DATE(YEAR(),3,31)` which indicates 31st of March. if you needed 1st Jul as start, then you would use `DATE(YEAR(),6,30)`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for someone. I had the same issue.

```
=IF((WEEKNUM(D4,16)-13)<=0,(WEEKNUM(D4,16)-13)+53,WEEKNUM(D4,16)-13)
```

"D4" is the current date

"16" is the day your fiscal year starts

The "-13" is the amount of weeks from 1/1/year to the first week that your fiscal year starts

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=WEEKNUM(DATEDIF("4/1/2018",TODAY()-1,"D"))
```

Comment: Please also explain your answer when answering a question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!